# Delete object single property from list

Tags: c#, linq

I want to delete object single property from list.  i have class,

```
Public class Employee
{
 public int Id {get;set;} 
 public string Name {get;set;}
 public string Address {get;set;}
}
```

and i have list,

```
List<Employee> lstEmployee = new List<Employee>();
```

Consider it has value like,

```
lstEmployee[0] = { Id = 0 , Name = "A" , Address = "ABC" }
lstEmployee[1] = { Id = 0 , Name = "B" , Address = "XYZ" }
lstEmployee[2] = { Id = 0 , Name = "C" , Address = "PQR" }
```

I want to delete property **Id** and rest record will remain as it is.

```
lstEmployee[0] = { Name = "A" , Address = "ABC" }
lstEmployee[1] = { Name = "B" , Address = "XYZ" }
lstEmployee[2] = { Name = "C" , Address = "PQR" }
```

Is it possible to achieve this? (Any other or alternate way)

Comment: No... create another object without id and copy

Comment: You can return the list without the ID field, is that what you want? It would require you to create an anonymous type...

Comment: Do you want to change the structure of the class? Or just remove a value from an object?

Comment: A good example of [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: @L.B -  you want me to create a **new class** which has only **Name** and **Address**  then Copy **old class** value to **new class** ?

Comment: @RiteshKumarJaiswal yes...

Comment: Better question is **why** does `Id` need to be removed?  Cant you just not use it, not show it, not consider it?

Comment: @Dido - I don't want to change structure of class just want to delete object property.

Comment: @RiteshKumarJaiswal Have you read the comment abot xy problem?

Comment: @RonBeyer - can u help me with example plse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This cannot be done because once the class definition is set, that's it.

The best you can do to retrieve an array of only the `Name` and `Address` 
 properties contained in an object is to use `LINQ` to perform an operation on each element, in which case you can then retrieve an array of anonymous types specifying exactly the properties you want.

example:

```
var result = (from e in lstEmployee
              select new { e.Name, e.Address }).ToArray();
```

Comment: can u share any example

Comment: can i make above code generic. A generic method which return list of anonymous type something

Comment: Actually i am not getting any help on internet

Comment: @RiteshKumarJaiswal one way to put the logic into a method and return the result is to make the method return type `dynamic` but I don't recommend this for many reasons. so take a moment and reconsider your entire approach. out of curiosity, why do you need to remove an object property?

Comment: Actually i have an existing logic which i can not change(render excel by taking list as input) and if i pass a list which has **Id** 0, it render even that **Id** column. My requirement is not to render **Id** as it is 0. So i thought before passing it to existing method, i will remove **Id** property from list object

Comment: it which case you can just copy the current class into a new class without the `id` property. it's bad practice to duplicate code but in this case, that's the best you can do.